# C++. Как спроектировать наследование Дерева Поиска в АВЛ

Tags: c++, наследование, структуры-данных, бинарное-дерево

Ломаю голову над тем, как правильно реализовать АВЛ-дерево на основе существующего бинарного поиска.

Есть шаблонный класс Узел, который хранит ключ и данные узла (некий словарь), указатели на поддеревья.

```
template <class T>
class Node
{
private:
    T _data;
    int _key;
    Node* _left, * _right;

public:
    friend class BinaryTree<T>;
}
```

Сам же шаблонный класс Дерево хранит указатель на корень и инварианты древа.

```
template <class T>
class BinaryTree
{
private:
    Node<T>* _root;
    int _height,
        _order;
}
```

Так вот, я хотел бы унаследовать это дерево, просто переопределив добавление, удаление (сделав функции виртуальными). Да и логично это - АВЛ это то же дерево, с единственным отличием - оно всегда сбалансировано.

Но возникает проблема - класс Узел. Для АВЛ дерева он должен содержать высоту относительно корня, для БДП это излишне, и как разрешить эту коллизию без костылей - я не знаю.

Comment: Эту коллизию никак нельзя разрешить. У обычного дерева и АВЛ-дерева должны быть разные типы узлов. А так как вам требуется создавать узлы, наследование не поможет.

Comment: Может  быть разумней будет реализовать свой вариант [map](https://cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)? В стандартном map внутри rb-tree, а у вас будет avl-tree

Comment: Ну это и есть по факту словарь, просто вопрос именно в организации наследования, так как код, не считая двух операций, абсолютно идентичен

Answer (score 3):

Способ есть, но вам не понравится. С использованием [CRTP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp).

Это также позволяет обойтись без виртуальных функций - что хорошо, потому что быстрее и не занимает места в классе. Но если вдруг захочется их добавить, то ничто не мешает это сделать (в реализации от них толку нет; есть смысл добавлять только как фичу для пользователей класса, если им позарез нужно использовать деревья полиморфно) (для этого добавляете родителя с единственным шаблонным параметром `template <typename T>`, от него наследуете `BasicBinaryTree`).

```
#include <iostream>

// Binary tree

template <typename DerivedNode, typename T>
struct BasicBinaryTreeNode
{
    // Для простоты все публичное.
    // Все равно из дерева не должны торчать наружу ноды, так?
    T value{};
    DerivedNode *left = nullptr;
    DerivedNode *right = nullptr;
};

template <typename Derived, typename Node, typename T>
class BasicBinaryTree
{
  protected:
    Node *left = nullptr;
    Node *right = nullptr;

    // Тестовая функция, внутренняя, которую будем переопределять в потомке.
    void TEST_modify_node(Node *) {}

  public:
    BasicBinaryTree() {}

    // Здесь функции родителя - бинарного дерева.

    // Тестовая функция.
    void TEST_add_node()
    {
        std::cout << "Adding node!\n";
        left = new Node;
        // Хитрый вызов, чтобы подхватить переопределение из потомка.
        static_cast<Derived *>(this)->TEST_modify_node(left);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct BinaryTreeNode : BasicBinaryTreeNode<BinaryTreeNode<T>, T> {};
template <typename T>
class BinaryTree : public BasicBinaryTree<BinaryTree<T>, BinaryTreeNode<T>, T>
{
  public:
    // Наследуем конструкторы.
    using BasicBinaryTree<BinaryTree<T>, BinaryTreeNode<T>, T>::BasicBinaryTree;
};

// AVL tree

// Казалось бы, этот класс избыточен, можно сразу вписать все в `AvlTreeNode`.
// Но тогда не получится сделать еще один уровень наследования, если он потом понадобится.
template <typename DerivedNode, typename T>
struct BasicAvlTreeNode : BasicBinaryTreeNode<DerivedNode, T>
{
    int height = 0;
};
template <typename T>
struct AvlTreeNode : BasicAvlTreeNode<AvlTreeNode<T>, T> {};

// Аналогично.
template <typename Derived, typename Node, typename T>
class BasicAvlTree : public BasicBinaryTree<Derived, Node, T>
{
    // Здесь функции потомка - AVL-дерева.
    // Тут в основном должны быть protected функции, в небольшом количестве.
    // Основная масса public функций - в родителе.

    friend BasicBinaryTree<Derived, Node, T>;

  protected:
    void TEST_modify_node(Node *x)
    {
        std::cout << "Setting height!\n";
        x->height = 1;
    }

  public:
    using BasicBinaryTree<Derived, Node, T>::BasicBinaryTree;
};

template <typename T>
class AvlTree : public BasicAvlTree<AvlTree<T>, AvlTreeNode<T>, T>
{
  public:
    using BasicAvlTree<AvlTree<T>, AvlTreeNode<T>, T>::BasicAvlTree;
};

// ---

// Пробуем:
int main()
{
    BinaryTree<int> x;
    x.TEST_add_node(); // Adding node!
    std::cout << "---\n";
    AvlTree<int> y;
    y.TEST_add_node(); // Adding node! Setting height!
}
```

Comment: Интересно, нужно будет вчитаться. Но на первый взгляд выглядит как усложнение кода несоразмерно задаче. Может, при подробном рассмотрении это окажется не так. Кстати говоря, Ноды могут торчать, например, функция find во многих пособиях по дискрмату возвращает не true/false, а адрес нода или нульптр

Comment: Спасибо за наводку на CRTP, не знал. Может, в код получиться аккуратно встроить

Comment: `find` в C++ возвращает итератор. Технически это указатель на узел, но этот факт от пользователя скрывают.

Comment: @Sublezuber Мне кажется проще никак не получится. Разве что не наследовать ноды друг от друга, а сделать два отдельных класса (но тогда придется скопипастить аж две строчки с определением `left` и `right` - ужас).

Comment: в питоне такой проблемы бы вообще не возникло за счет динамической типизации. Там дерево унаследовал, а при обработке используешь нагруженный узел. А как в С++ обойти ограничение типов, не прибегая к костылям вроде копирования кода - обусфакция; нагружения обычного дерева - выделение лишней памяти; либо создание еще шаблонного подкласса data в node в качестве контейнерного подкласса, содержащего помимо пользовательского типа еще и данные об узле. Но это все костыли. Я постараюсь реализовать на основе того, что вы сказали, посмотрю кап будет выглядеть и дам фидбек)

Comment: @Sublezuber *"в питоне такой проблемы бы вообще не возникло"* Это переводится как "оно работало бы неоптимально, но по коду это было бы незаметно, потому что питон все сам делает". Так-то и в плюсах можно было бы довольно просто напихать виртуальных функций и в дерево, и в ноду, и `dynamic_cast`-овать при необходимости, и результат был бы примерно такой же.

Comment: Кто ж про оптимальность говорит?) я сам люблю больше плюсы, но очевидное преимущество питона - он №2 язык в любой сфере. Ну и вопрос не в том, что мне виртуальные функции надо напихать. Мне надо унаследовать дерево, только с расширенной структурой данных вместо обычной, в реализации остальных функций проблем нет)

Answer (score 0):

Из всех зол выбрал наименьшее:
в шаблон добавил параметр по умолчанию, принимающий тип узла, в теле класса старые типы Node заменил на шаблонный тип:

```
template <typename T, class TypeNode = Node<T>>
class BinaryTree{
    ...
    BinaryTree(BinaryTree<T, TypeNode>&& other) noexcept;
    ...
    TypeNode* find(int) const;
    ...
};
```

При этом инициализация осталась прежней:

```
BinaryTree<int> tree(key, data, 16); // 16 - размер массивов key и data
```

Для АВЛ-дерева написал свой контейнер узла (минимальное дублирование кода):

```
template <typename T>
class AVLNode
{
public:
    T _data;
    int _key;
    AVLNode* _left, * _right;
    int _height;

public:
    friend class AVLTree<T>;        // для того, что бы AVLTree имел доступ к полям и методам AVLNode
    ...
}
```

Ну и унаследовал, собственно, само дерево, подставляя в качестве контейнера AVLNode:

```
template <typename T, class TypeNode>
class AVLTree : public BinaryTree<T, AVLNode<T>>
{
public:
    AVLTree() : BinaryTree<T, AVLNode<T>>() {
    }
    ...
}
```

**Для более изящного решения нужно унаследовать сам AVL-узел. я столкнулся со следующей проблемой:**

```
template <typename T>
class AVLNode : public Node<T> 
{
protected:
    int _height;

public:
    friend class AVLTree<T>;
    ...
};
```

при такой структуре указатели нода все равно остаются не авл, поэтому вариантов два:

1. сделать их приватными, добавить и в AVL, и в BST с нужным типом - дублирование кода, смысл тогда наследовали?
2. сделать для нода такой же шаблонный параметр, как и для BST, но тогда встает вопрос с параметром по умолчанию: он будет классом, параметром шаблона которого он является - ошибка компиляции. как разрешить - вопрос.